# Windows 8 Effects

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-8

This might not be a question specific to Windows 8, C#, WPF. But I have no idea on what tags should I put on this. I am currently working on a system that is supposed to be 'futuristic' - a term that is varies from people.

As I watched this presentation from Windows 8 team on YouTube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p92QfWOw88I), I starts to wondering if I could do something similar to that. So what could be the technologies involved behind this? And where can I find more resources about this?

I want to create something similar to this where we can utilize more on the Touch, create the tiles, the sliding and so on. Something that wouldn't be the same from the normal Windows UX to achieve the 'futuristic'.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: It's a really vague question. But learning WPF would be a really good starting point. Please be more specific.

Comment: Windows 8 new UI screens are going to use html5 and JavaSript.

Comment: I am currently investigate into WPF but that's seems more than WPF. I am pretty sure if Windows can does it. It means that we can create a similar UX inside the app as well. So I am wondering what has been used to create that.

Comment: Ohya, just for some information, I am thinking of creating this inside Windows 7 itself instead of Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

[MetroDynamis](http://metrodynamis.com/) is the first (and only, so far) attempt I've seen at replicating the new Metro/tiles interface of Windows 8. If you really wanted to have an interactive UI with touch capabilities and all, your best framework option is WPF.

Aside from the stated HTML5 and Javascript way of programming tiles, rumors exist that Microsoft project "Jupiter" will provide a Tiles UI framework. Jupiter is thought to be .NET 4.5 or something along those lines. There is no clear indication as to whether or not this will work with Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 2):

When I watched this video, I had WPF in my head the whole time. If you want a similar user experience in your app, I would probably focus on using WPF.

The big reason I was thinking WPF was the fact that Windows 8 is heavily based on a tiling system. WPF `Grid` control would probably be perfect for the tile layout, including the snap feature. When mixed with a `Canvas` or something, it would probably also be great for the one-finger app-switching that was shown.

They also mentioned that developers could use web-based technologies to build their apps, which is quite interesting. It seems to me that the HTML / CSS (or whatever other layout technologies are common for the web) could be easily implemented using WPF (if it hasn't been already). Also, there's probably already a way to use JavaScript with WPF in a simple fashion. If not, I'm sure JScript .Net could prove helpful. (I'm not sure if you were interested in this part, or if you were only focused on the layout and touch capabilities).

As far as touch capabilities go, I believe that your app would process it in the same (or a similar) way as mouse input. So there's not much work there. The physics for things like the smooth scrolling shouldn't be too hard either, as there are tons of touch demos out there. They shouldn't be too difficult to find. (One example is the [Hilo](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Hilo-0e6f10bf) demo, which I've taken a quick gander at. The end result is a rather interesting yet simple photo viewing app). Even if these demos aren't written for WPF, it wouldn't be that hard to translate late the algorithms over to your WPF app.

Lastly, WPF is hands-down a great development tool. It's very neat and organized, and possesses some pretty fascinating capabilities. It is also based on DirectX, which could be a particularly favorable feature depending on what you decide to do exactly. Also, since I am an avid C# fan, I always give bonus points to technologies implemented on .Net.

Anyways, those are just some reasons I would recommend a WPF based approach. I see a whole lot of reasons to use it, and just about no reasons for not using it.

Comment: I agree that most of the things can be done in WPF. I created this post just to collect more opinion and in hope of getting into more possibility. However, it seems that WPF is what have been recommended by most people and I am quite sure that I am on the right path.